# could fsck -Af -M cause corrupt filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3, corruption, fsck

Last night my server encounter "Read-only file system" error.

So then I ran "fsck -Af -M" to trying to repair but no use, these are output:

```
fsck 1.39 (29-May-2006)
e2fsck 1.39 (29-May-2006)
/: recovering journal
fsck.ext3: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to re-open /
e2fsck: io manager magic bad!
```

After I reboot the server, I can't even recover the filesystem anymore and must reinstall the OS. My / was RAID 1 and ext3 formated. Did that fsck command cause my filesystem corrupted? or it has been corrupted before I run fsck?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would try using a backup super-block, but you'll need to know the filesystem's blocksize.

From the [e2fsck man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck):

> The location of the backup superblock is dependent on the filesystem’s
>   blocksize.   For  filesystems  with  1k blocksizes,  a  backup 
>   superblock  can be found at block 8193; for filesystems with 2k
>   block-sizes, at block 16384; and for 4k blocksizes, at block 32768.

As an example, this command is for a `1K` blocksize filesystem:

```
fsck.ext3 -b 8193 /dev/sda2
```

Good luck!

Comment: But I want to know for sure if running "fsck -Af -M" cause my filesystem corrupted or others reason. I want to prevent this issue in the future :)

Comment: Probably not, because you used the `-M` option.  This would've prevented it from scanning the mounted filesystem.

Comment: thanks for your reply, now I must find the real root cause that corrupted my file system.